# How to put text in an animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, visualization

I am trying to put text in a matplotlib animation. (Hopefully *outside* the plot, but I am not worrying about that yet)

I tried to follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69289636/4451521), however my code is a bit complicated in that it does not gives only one line every time.
Here  is my code

```
import math
import argparse
import os
import json
import sys

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation ,FFMpegWriter


line_x=[ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12  ]
line1_y=[ 3,5,7,9,11,19,23,26,29,31,37,40,45  ]
line2_y=[0,2,5,7,10,10,8,5,3,2,1,3,5]
line3_y=[39,38,32,29,26,22,19,13,10,8,7,6,3]

set_lines=[line1_y,line2_y,line3_y]

n_lineas=[1,2,3,1,3,2,3,1,3,2,1,2]

show=True

thecolors=['blue','red','violet']
thelegends=['unus','duo','tres']

print(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv)==2 and sys.argv[1]=='movie':
    show=False


def get_n(thelist,c):
    while(c>=len(thelist)):
        c-len(thelist)
    return thelist[c]


class Update:
    def __init__(self,ax,limit_x):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lx=limit_x
        if limit_x!=0:
            self.ax.set_xlim(0,limit_x)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0,45)
        self.ax.set_aspect('equal')
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.lines=()
        self.counter=0
        self.text=self.ax.text(0,0,'')

    def __call__(self, frame):
        print("Frame: ",frame)
        lines=[]

        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.set_xlim(0,self.lx)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0,45)
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Y (meters)")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("X (meters)")

        n_lines_this_time=get_n(n_lineas,self.counter)
        self.counter+=1
        print(n_lines_this_time,"lines this time")

        for myline in range(n_lines_this_time):
            #line,=self.ax.plot([],[],'.-',color=gt_color,label=legend)
            line,=self.ax.plot([],[],'.-',color=thecolors[myline],label=thelegends[myline])
            x = []
            y = []
            for v in range(13):
                x.append(line_x[v])
                y.append(set_lines[myline][v])
            line.set_xdata(x)
            line.set_ydata(y)
            lines.append(line)

        plt.legend()
        self.lines=tuple(lines)
        self.text.set_text("Frame "+str(frame))
        self.text.set_position((0,0))
        #return self.lines,self.text  #<---HERE this does not work!!!
        return self.lines


    def init(self):
        print("Init")
        line,=self.ax.plot([],[])
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Y (meters)")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("X (meters)")
        self.text.set_text('')
        self.text.set_position((0,0))
        return line,self.text,
        #return line,



fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,figsize=(10,10))
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect(
        'key_release_event',
        lambda event: [exit(0) if event.key == 'escape' else None])
plt.xlabel("Y (meters)") 
plt.ylabel("X (meters)")
plt.legend()

ug_i = Update(ax,13)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, ug_i,init_func=ug_i.init, frames=10, interval=1000, blit=True,repeat=False)

if not show:  
    writervideo = FFMpegWriter(fps=1)
    anim.save('whatever.mp4', writer=writervideo)
    print('done')
    plt.close()
else:
    #plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

In the current state, the text does not show (of course) but when I try to return it (as marked above in a comment ("HERE") ) it crashes giving me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kansai/miniconda3/envs/roscv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1194, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kansai/miniconda3/envs/roscv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1442, in _step
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "/home/kansai/miniconda3/envs/roscv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1173, in _step
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "/home/kansai/miniconda3/envs/roscv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1192, in _draw_next_frame
    self._draw_frame(framedata)
  File "/home/kansai/miniconda3/envs/roscv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1748, in _draw_frame
    key=lambda x: x.get_zorder())
  File "/home/kansai/miniconda3/envs/roscv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1748, in <lambda>
    key=lambda x: x.get_zorder())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_zorder'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is failing and how can I display the text? (if outside the plot much better)

Answer (score 0):

After un-commenting your line of code, I didn't get any error, however the text was not visible. So, instead of using `ax.text` I tried `fig.text`: now the text is visible outside the plotting area.

```py
import math
import argparse
import os
import json
import sys

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation ,FFMpegWriter


line_x=[ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12  ]
line1_y=[ 3,5,7,9,11,19,23,26,29,31,37,40,45  ]
line2_y=[0,2,5,7,10,10,8,5,3,2,1,3,5]
line3_y=[39,38,32,29,26,22,19,13,10,8,7,6,3]

set_lines=[line1_y,line2_y,line3_y]

n_lineas=[1,2,3,1,3,2,3,1,3,2,1,2]

show=True

thecolors=['blue','red','violet']
thelegends=['unus','duo','tres']

# print(sys.argv)
# if len(sys.argv)==2 and sys.argv[1]=='movie':
#     show=False


def get_n(thelist,c):
    while(c>=len(thelist)):
        c-len(thelist)
    return thelist[c]


class Update:
    def __init__(self,fig,ax,limit_x):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lx=limit_x
        if limit_x!=0:
            self.ax.set_xlim(0,limit_x)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0,45)
        self.ax.set_aspect('equal')
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.lines=()
        self.counter=0
        self.text=fig.text(0.15,0.5,'')

    def __call__(self, frame):
        print("Frame: ",frame)
        lines=[]

        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.set_xlim(0,self.lx)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0,45)
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Y (meters)")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("X (meters)")

        n_lines_this_time=get_n(n_lineas,self.counter)
        self.counter+=1
        print(n_lines_this_time,"lines this time")

        for myline in range(n_lines_this_time):
            #line,=self.ax.plot([],[],'.-',color=gt_color,label=legend)
            line,=self.ax.plot([],[],'.-',color=thecolors[myline],label=thelegends[myline])
            x = []
            y = []
            for v in range(13):
                x.append(line_x[v])
                y.append(set_lines[myline][v])
            line.set_xdata(x)
            line.set_ydata(y)
            lines.append(line)

        plt.legend()
        self.lines=tuple(lines)
        self.text.set_text("Frame "+str(frame))
        return self.lines,self.text  #<---HERE this does not work!!!
        return self.lines


    def init(self):
        print("Init")
        line,=self.ax.plot([],[])
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Y (meters)")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("X (meters)")
        self.text.set_text('')
        return line,self.text,
        #return line,



fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect(
        'key_release_event',
        lambda event: [exit(0) if event.key == 'escape' else None])
plt.xlabel("Y (meters)") 
plt.ylabel("X (meters)")
plt.legend()

ug_i = Update(fig,ax,13)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, ug_i,init_func=ug_i.init, frames=10, interval=1000, blit=True,repeat=False)

if not show:  
    writervideo = FFMpegWriter(fps=1)
    anim.save('whatever.mp4', writer=writervideo)
    print('done')
    plt.close()
else:
    #plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```